# FFT Window question - high resolution windows

Tags: fft, window-functions, superresolution

So I am pretty familiar with FFTs and FFT windows. I know that in general there is a tradeoff between mainlobe width and sidelobe levels.

However, I recently stumbled across [this discussion](https://forum.digilent.com/topic/4131-just-for-fun-frequency-resolution-challenge/), where someone claims to have created a window or FFT method that achieves both very good mainlobe resolution AND very low sidelobes. However, he doesn't explain the technique.

Looking at the frequency response, I get the impression that there is maybe some upsampling/nonlinear method involved, or maybe some iterative technique.

Does anyone know how this might be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I also have some experience with FFT and windowing. I have also tried several times to reduce the amplitude of sidelobes. What is claimed on the site you mentioned is fake. Forget it.